# scikit learn creation of dummy variables

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

In scikit-learn, which models do I need to break categorical variables into dummy binary fields?

For example, if the column is `political-party`, and the values are `democrat`, `republican` and `green`, for many algorithms, you have to break this into three columns where each row can only hold one `1`, and all the rest must be `0`.

This avoids enforcing an ordinality that doesn't exist when discretizing `[democrat, republican and green]` => `[0, 1, 2]`, since `democrat` and `green` aren't actually "farther" away then another pair.

For which algorithms in scikit-learn is this transformation into dummy variables necessary? And for those algorithms that aren't, it can't hurt, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For which algorithms in scikit-learn is this transformation into dummy variables necessary? And for those algorithms that aren't, it can't hurt, right?

All algorithms in sklearn with the notable exception of tree-based methods require one-hot encoding (also known as dummy variables) for nominal categorical variables.

Using dummy variables for categorical features with very large cardinalities might hurt tree-based methods, especially randomized tree methods by introducing a bias in the feature split sampler. Tree-based method tend to work reasonably well with a basic integer encoding of categorical features.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are saying that since RF will take a random subset of the columns, it very well might take all the zero columns and miss the only information (the 1)? Is there a way to make RF pick/leave features as groups instead of single indexed columns?

Comment: Indeed, this would introduce a sampling bias in the feature split, but no catastrophic failure as RF will keep on sampling for new features until it finds one that is not constant (e.g. not all zeros).

Comment: @larsmans, ogrisel said "Using dummy variables...might hurt tree-based methods...by introducing a bias...", but you are saying that using dummy variables prevents bias. Which argument are you supporting?

Comment: @ogrisel I don't understand your point. By definition a dummy variable column can never be constant 0's, correct? otherwise one-hot encoding wouldn't have created the column.

Comment: After a couple of splits, the samples that reach a specific node can very well all have a specific feature that is uniformly zero valued.

Answer (score 0):

For any algorithm that does calculations based on vectorized inputs (the large majority of them, but I'm sure there are exceptions), you will need to do some kind of "vectorization". However, you don't have to do it in the way you've explained above.

Since most of the algorithms only care that they are being given a series of numbers mapped to a series other numbers, you are generally able to replace any binary fields with confidence levels if you have that level of granularity.

It's also worth noting that these are not "dummy variables", but are just a different representation. They directly represent your classes. To answer your last question, it can only hurt if you're throwing away information, so turning a classification into a binary vector is totally fine. To put this into more concrete terms:

```
['republican'] -> [0, 1, 0] # binary vectorization, totally fine

['republican', 'green'] -> [0, 0.5, 0.5] # non-binary vectorization, also totally fine

{'republican': 0.75, 'green': 0.25} -> [0, 1, 0] # information lost, not fine.
```

Hope that helps, let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: I don't understand your examples. I'm interested in storing the categorical options in as little space as possible without enforcing ordinality where there isn't any.